# R: argument matches multiple formal arguments

Tags: r, excel

I tried to read-in data from a excel file which contains multiple spread sheets.

```
    setwd("C:/Users/XXX/XXX")
    getwd()
    rm(list=ls())

    require(xlsx)
    df =read.xlsx("data.csv",sheet=3, colNames = TRUE)
```

once I run this code, it always come back with this error message :

```
    Error in read.xlsx("dt.csv", sheet = 3,  :argument 2 matches multiple formal arguments
```

I don't know what to do. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 22):

The two arguments to the `read.xlsx` method that match `sheet` are `sheetIndex` and `sheetName`, according to the signature:

```
read.xlsx(file, sheetIndex, sheetName=NULL, rowIndex=NULL,
  startRow=NULL, endRow=NULL, colIndex=NULL,
  as.data.frame=TRUE, header=TRUE, colClasses=NA,
  keepFormulas=FALSE, encoding="unknown", ...)
```

You need the `sheetIndex` argument:

```
df =read.xlsx("data.csv",sheetIndex=3, colNames = TRUE)
```